# Is SL4A reliable enought for an important task?

Tags: android, python, sl4a, pika

I'm working on an stock control system client for android, being little experienced on python and not knowing anything about java, I decided to work with SL4A Python.

I'm using rabbitmq and pika library as my base. I got pika library working under android.

The problem is, if my code fails even for a few hours, it will hurt our project fatally. Does SL4A considered reliable enough?

Does making it into an APK with buildozer makes it more or less stable?

Comment: In my opion is not fully reliable, Im a python lover but for this task im not sure if it is the best tool...

Comment: +1 @DanielSanchez ... SL4A is really nice, but if you're using it for something critical, you need to implement redundancy yourself. It can't be depended on.